# Problema al pasar un ComboBox como argumento

Tags: excel, funciones, vba, combobox, ordenamiento

Aclaro que soy relativamente nueva en esto y tengo problemas al pasar un ComboBox como argumento en una Subrutina. Antes usaba un subproceso para ordenar el contenido de cada ComboBox y lo que intento ahora es reducir codigo.

Explico:
La forma contiene N ComboBox(1, 2, ... N) que se llenan con el contenido de una columna de tabla cada uno. Por ejemplo:

```
Set NColumn = TStaff.ListColumns("NameStaff").DataBodyRange
Me.ComboBox1.List = NColumn.value
SortComboBox1

Set IDColumn = TStaff.ListColumns("IDStaff").DataBodyRange
Me.ComboBox2.List = IDColumn.value
SortComboBox2

...

SortComboBoxN
```

El codigo empleado para ordenar el contenido de cada ComboBox es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub SortComboBox1()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sTemp As String
Dim LbList As Variant

LbList = Me.ComboBox1.List

For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
        If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then

            sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
            LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
            LbList(j, 0) = sTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Me.ComboBox1.Clear

Me.ComboBox1.List = LbList
End Sub

Private Sub SortComboBox2()
...
End sub

...

Private Sub SortComboBoxN()
...
End sub
```

Lo que busco es un subproceso que reciba como argumento cualquier ComboBox (o su contenido) y evitar repetir el mismo codigo para ordenar cada ComboBox.

Mi primer enforque fue este pero se produce el "error 424" (Se requiere un objeto):

Modulo1:

```
Public CBox As ComboBox
```

UserForm(Codigo)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
...
Me.ComboBox1.List = NColumn.value
SortCBox (Me.ComboBox1)
Me.ComboBox2.List = IDColumn.value
SortCBox (Me.ComboBox2)
End Sub

Private Sub SortCBox(CBox As ComboBox)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim sTemp As String
Dim LbList As Variant

LbList = CBox.List 

For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
        If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then
            sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
            LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
            LbList(j, 0) = sTemp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

CBox.Clear

CBox.List = LbList
End Sub
```

Donde esta el problema?? 
*Si alguien tiene otro enforque agradezo por las sugerencias

Comment: Quizá este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23121137/7558682) te ayude.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Cuando creas un argumento para un Sub o una Function, no necesitas definir esa variable. Es decir, tú tienes `Private Sub SortCBox(CBox As ComboBox)` pero luego creas una variable pública que se llama igual que ese argumento. Esa variable pública está vacía (en tu código no la asignas nunca a ningún objeto) y por eso creo que te da el error. Borra `Public CBox As ComboBox` (o usa un nombre diferente) y prueba